# Is it good practice to use the Content folder in ASP.NET MVC as File System to store PDF Files?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, filesystems

So I need a place (file system/folder) to store static PDF files for my ASP.NET MVC app. It will be around 36 pdf files a year. Can't use a database for this project.

So my questions is, is it good practice to store those 36 pdf files/a year in the 'Content' folder? Or should I instead store it in a folder outside the website structure? For people who don't store pdf files on the database, where do they usually store it? I'm concern storing all those files in the 'Content' folder is gonna affect performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these PDF files private or belongs to users inside your application? If not, then just store it to your Content folder.

Comment: Nope, these PDF files just have basic info to supplement the website. So if I put the PDF files on the Content folder, will there be a 'limit' for how many PDF files should be in that Content folder before it starts affecting performance? like if there's 500 PDF files there, is that 'too much'?

Comment: I think the only time that you would encounter slowing down is when you're building the application and deploying it, since the PDF files have to be uploaded, this will depend on your internet connection.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better to store the PDF files in another folder outside of the website structure so it doesn't affect deployment? So for example: 1. Master folder -> 2A. Website Folder (here is where all the files for the website is), 2B. PDF Folder (store the pdf files here)? or this not a 'thing' that anyone does?

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's definitely better. You could just provide them a link (download anchor tag) that will lead to that file. I wasn't able to think of that because I was focused on keeping it within the project.